I used DinkToPdf for converting html to pdf.I need borders in all pages.But getting a continuous border
    public async Task<string> FreeFlowDefectRenderToHtmlAsync(DefectFreeFlowDetailsResponseDto defectFreeFlowExportList)
    

    {
        string path;
        string content;


       if (defectFreeFlowExportList.items !=null && defectFreeFlowExportList.items.Count > 0)
        {
           path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/Views/FreeFlowDefectReport.cshtml");
            content= await RenderPartialToStringAsync(path, defectFreeFlowExportList.items);
        }
         else
         {
           path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/Views/FreeFlowAuditDefectReport.cshtml");
           content= await RenderPartialToStringAsync(path, defectFreeFlowExportList.AuditItems);
         }

/// Define the border style
var style = ".page-border { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 2px solid #4a4a4a; padding: 0.5px; box-sizing: border-box; }";
// Split the content by page breaks
var pages = content.Split(new[] { "<div class=\"breakhere\"></div>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

// Add border only to pages all pages
for (int i = 0; i < pages.Length; i++)
{
    pages[i] = $"<div class=\"page-border\">{pages[i]}</div>";
}

// Reassemble the pages
var wrappedContent = $"{style}{string.Join("<div class=\"breakhere\"></div>", pages)}";

return wrappedContent;

I need border in all pages.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
